# Who do I have "</script> attempted to close an element that was not open" in a simple coding that only has one script block

Tags: javascript, svelte

I'm in my first month into Svelte and I'm having this strange error with this coding:

```
<script>
    let name = 'world'
</script>

<input bind:value={name}>

<h1>
    Helllo {name}!
</h1>
```

As you can see, I'm doing my first binding with input element and I got the next error message:

```
</script> attempted to close an element that was not open *svelte(invalid-closing-tag) [Ln 10, Col 1]*
```

I don't even have a 10 line, the code only has 9 lines.

I also received the same error but with js instead of svelte, in the same code at the same time.

```
</script> attempted to close an element that was not open *js(-1) [Ln 10, Col 1]*
```

These are my errors.

[Console errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1MMS9.png)

Comment: It looks like an issue with your project setup configuration because it works in the svelte_repl- https://svelte.dev/repl/f2dbbce402ae41eba4859e51059b134b?version=4.2.0. Consider following https://kit.svelte.dev/ to set up your sveltekit project.

Answer (score -1):

Add a closing slash to your input element.

```html
<input bind:value={name}/>
```